# Simple Injector: Register Conditional vs RegisterSingleton

Tags: asp.net-web-api, serilog, simple-injector

Context: I am trying to capture multiple events in our api using serilog and the elastic search sink, these events include: GET actions(regular web api flow) as well as login attempts (Owin).
I am registering serilog like this:

```
container.RegisterConditional(
    typeof(ICustomLogger),
    c => typeof(CustomLogger<>).MakeGenericType(
        c.Consumer?.ImplementationType ?? typeof(object)),
    Lifestyle.Singleton,
    c => true);
```

I am doing this for Owin registration:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    using (var scope = container.BeginExecutionContextScope())
    {
        await next.Invoke();
    }
});
```

Then when I call  `container.Verify();` the logger constructor gets called(as expected).
However when I call the logger from my `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider` implementation like this:
`var logger = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ICustomLogger>();` the constructor gets called again, meaning the singleton is not really a singleton anymore, I am totally aware of the service locator antipattern(don't really have much time to refactor that piece right now), what is interesting is that if I change the logger registration to the following (getting rid of the type piece) then only one instance is created:

```
container.RegisterSingleton(typeof(ICustomLogger), typeof(CustomLogger))
```

The reason why I am trying to use the first option is because I want to be able to use `.ForContext(typeof(T));` for serilog, and in case you are wondering how I am registering the `ObjectFactory` piece here it is:
Class:

```
public static class ObjectFactory
{
    public static Container container;

    public static void SetContainer(Container container)
    {
        ObjectFactory.container = container;
    }

    public static T GetInstance<T>() where T : class
    {
        return container.GetInstance<T>();
    }
}
```

Registration(from my main bootstrapper):

```
ObjectFactory.SetContainer(container);
```

So my main question is: Why is only one instance created with `RegisterSingleton` but multiple are created with `RegisterConditional` and `Lifestyle.Singleton`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason multiple instances are created has nothing to do with the fact that you are using your `ObjectFactory`, but simply because different closed versions of `CustomLogger<T>` are created:

- A `CustomLogger<object>` is created when resolved as root type (by calling `GetInstance<ICustomLogger>()`
- A `CustomLogger<Service1>` is created when `ICustomLogger` is injected into `Service1`.

Because a `CustomLogger<object>` is a *different type* than a `CustomLogger<Service1>`, it is impossible to have just one instance for both types. They both have to be created. This might seem weird, but consider these two classes:

```cs
public class Service1
{
    public Service1(ICustomLogger logger) { }
}

public class Service2
{
    public Service2(ICustomLogger logger) { }
}
```

At runtime, considering these two definitions, you want to create object graphs similar to the following:

```cs
var s1 = new Service1(new CustomLogger<Service1>());
var s2 = new Service2(new CustomLogger<Service2>());
```

In the above case, the `CustomLogger`s are not cached and are, therefore, effectively transients. You might try to rewrite this to the following, but that would not be the same:

```cs
ICustomLogger logger = new CustomLogger<Service1>();
var s1 = new Service1(logger);
var s2 = new Service2(logger);
```

Now both service get the same single instance. However, this means that `Service2` gets a `CustomLogger<Service1>` which is not what you configured. You configured the dependency to be this:

```
typeof(CustomLogger<>).MakeGenericType(c.Consumer.ImplementationType)
```

Consequence of this is that when `Service2` starts to log, it will look like if the messages are coming from `Service1`. This would likely be incorrect behavior. Otherwise, you could have simply called `RegisterSingleton<ICustomLogger, CustomLogger<Service1>>()`.

This all means that the *Singleton* guarantee for a `RegisterConditional` that uses an implementation-type factory (as in your example) only holds for the specified closed generic type.

Note that `RegisterConditional` isn't the only part in Simple Injector where you see this behavior. The following registrations do have the same effect:

```cs
container.RegisterSingleton(typeof(IFoo<>), typeof(Foo<>));

container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(IFoo<>), typeof(FooDecorator<>), Lifestyle.Singleton);
```

In both these cases multiple instances of closed generic versions of `Foo<T>` and `FooDecorator<T>` can be created, but Simple Injector guarantees that there is only one instance of every closed-generic version of `Foo<T>`. With `RegisterDecorator<T>`, however, even that is not guaranteed. Consider this example:

```cs
container.Collection.Append<ILogger, Logger1>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
container.Collection.Append<ILogger, Logger2>(Lifestyle.Singleton);

container.RegisterDecorator<ILogger, LoggerDecorator>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
```

In this case, a collection of `ILogger` components is registered where each `ILogger` element will be wrapped with a `LoggerDecorator`. Because a `LoggerDecorator` can only depend on either `Logger1` or `Logger2`, but not both, Simple Injector will have to create a new `LoggerDecorator` instance for each element. If the `LoggerDecorator` would be cached as a true Singleton, this would be the result:

```cs
private static ILogger logger = new LoggerDecorator(new Logger1());

private static loggers = new[] { logger, logger };
```

As there is only 1 single `LoggerDecorator`, this decorator depends on `Logger1`, which means that the collection of loggers only has two elements that both point to the same `Logger1` instance. There is no `Logger2`.

This information is reflected in the following Simple Injector documentation sections:

- [Aspect-Oriented Programming - Applying Lifestyles to Decorators](https://simpleinjector.org/aop+applying-lifestyles-to-decorators)
- [Lifetime Management - Generics and Lifetime Management](https://simpleinjector.org/lifetimes+generics-and-lifetime-management)

Comment: Hi @Steven, thanks for the prompt response and excellent answer, that clarifies everything. I think I am going to have to give up on capturing the caller context because I have a file sink as a fallback on my logger and multiple instances would cause issues when they all are trying to write to the file(this is actually how I discovered multiple instances were being created). Thanks for all your help!